# Iterating over rows in google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am working on a bar chart, and for some rows I have a particular column which contains link, now on ready event I want to iterate over all the rows to find out what is the link, if link is `type a` I want to set element color red, otherwise not.

```
cols: [
  {
     id: 'first value',
     label: 'name',
     type: 'string'
  },
  {
     id: 'second value',
     label: 'type',
     type: 'number'
  },
],
rows: [
  {
     c: [
       {
          v: 'apple'
       },
       {
          v: 24,
          link : 'type A or type B '
       },
    ]
  },
]
```

Any help about this ?

Comment: use `getFilteredRows` -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39946553/5090771)