# Using getFillteredRows in google charts with additional property

Tags: google-visualization

I have a row structure like this

```
c:[
  { v: 'somevalue'},
  { v: 'somevalue'},
  { 
    v: 'somevalue',
    link: 'abc.com'
  }    
]
```

now I need all the rows which has link property present in 3rd column, is it possible using getFillteredRows function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, to use *cell* properties correctly, the structure would resemble the following...

```
c:[
  { v: 'somevalue'},
  { v: 'somevalue'},
  { 
    v: 'somevalue',
    p: {
      link: 'abc.com'
    }
  }    
]
```

to *get* or *set* the properties, use the following [methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods)...

`getProperty(rowIndex, columnIndex, name)`

`setProperty(rowIndex, columnIndex, name, value)`

adding in [`getFilteredRows`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getFilteredRows) (spelling - one L in filter)...

use the `test` function, to find *all the rows which has link property present in 3rd column*

```
var rowsFound = data.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 2,
  test: function (value, row, column, table) {
    return (table.getProperty(row, column, 'link') !== null);
  }
}]);
```